# How can I map the "Archived" folder to "All Mail"?

Tags: macos, mail.app, gmail

I would like to map the "Archived" folder that's created when you Archive mail to the "All Mail" folder in my Gmail account.  How can I do this?

Comment: Related question on superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/315171/how-to-stop-mail-app-in-lion-creating-an-archive-folder-for-archiving-in-gmail

Comment: Actually, there is a solution:

http://superuser.com/questions/315171/how-to-stop-mail-app-in-lion-creating-an-archive-folder-for-archiving-in-gmail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in Lion. [File a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) if you want to be able to do this.

Comment: I was afraid this was going to be the answer...

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. To help matter, though, you can create a keyboard shortcut (in Keyboard preferences) for Message > Move To > All Mail.

Comment: I have multiple accounts (all Gmail) so, I would need to create 3 different shortcuts.  I created an AppleScript to move messages to [Gmail]/All Mail though and then created a service so I can run it from a shortcut.  The AppleScript is here:  https://gist.github.com/1134751  I'm not thrilled with it's performance though.

Comment: @Owen: http://www.indev.ca/MailActOn.html

Answer (score 4):

For some reason stackexchange isn't letting me comment on the approved answer.

In any case, jtbandes' comment is incomplete, you have to set the custom app shortcut as:

"**Message>Move To>All Mail**"

Note the **lack** of spaces between the words. This is critical; it won't work otherwise. Simply typing "All Mail" will trigger multiple, redundantly named menu items with the keyboard shortcut.

I've assigned mine to Command-Y to approximate the Gmail shortcut.

I learned this from a comment by LaraCroft_NYC at https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2572960?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: I think your "comment" works great as a workaround answer :-) The reason you couldn't comment is your [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) the more you commit the more privileged you are. Hint: if you read through the FAQ, you will also get a shiny [Analytical](http://apple.stackexchange.com/badges/74/analytical) [badge](http://apple.stackexchange.com/badges) as a reward.

Answer (score 0):

The odd thing is that for me, until this morning, (Aug 11/11) the archive button was sending emails to the All Mail folder. Suddenly today Mail created a new "archive" folder and is now putting archived emails there instead of All Mail.

I thought was dreaming, but I checked my all mail folder and I have emails there dated since I upgraded to Lion until yesterday.

Huh?

Comment: That's expecially strange since the Mail help states: "An Archive mailbox is created for each account whose messages you archive. For example, if you archive a message sent to your MobileMe account and a message sent to your Gmail account, an Archive mailbox is created for each account.

Archived messages remain in the Archive mailbox until you delete or move them. Depending on the account type, the Archive mailbox is stored on the mail server."